# Understanding OrdinalEncoder syntax

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm having troubles understanding the syntax of `OrdinalEncoder`.

In the documentation, for me it's not so clear in the example provided:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
enc = OrdinalEncoder()
X = [['Male', 1], ['Female', 3], ['Female', 2]]
enc.fit(X)
enc.categories_
[array(['Female', 'Male'], dtype=object), array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)]
enc.transform([['Female', 3], ['Male', 1]])
```

outputs: `array([[0., 2.], [1., 0.]])`

My first question is be what the matrix `X` represents here? Because with a code like:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
enc = OrdinalEncoder(categories = [["Low", "High", "Medium"]])
df[["ScoreText"]] = enc.fit_transform(df[["ScoreText"]])
```

Works aswell, and for me seems easier to understand. However, why `categories` has to be a `matrix` tho?

My second question is why we need to add a double `[]` when transforming one column of the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your questions one by one.

1. **What does the matrix `X` represent?** To me it seems to represent a list of three observations with two attributes each, i.e. the indication of the gender and a number. For example, `['Male', 1]` is one observation and `['Female', 3]` is another.
2. **Why has `categories` to be a matrix?** For this, you should consult the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html). It is stated there that:

> `categories[i]` holds the categories expected in the ith column.

Hence, `categories` is a list of array-likes so it can be determined which categories are meant for which columns, in case you transform more than one column.

3. **Why do we need to add a double `[]` when transforming one column of the dataframe?** This is due to the indexing and selecting rules of `pandas`. Actually, if you want to select only one column, a single label in single `[]` would be sufficient (e.g. `df["ScoreText"]`). However, `pandas` will then return a `Series` object which is a 1d ndarray of shape `(n_samples, )`. In contrast, when selecting a single column with double `[]` a `DataFrame` object with shape of `(n_samples, 1)` will be returned. This difference is important for compatibility reasons, as many transformers or encoders await a 2d array-like (which a `Series` is not). For more about the indexing and selection rules, read the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

---

### Edit

In the first example, `OrdinalEncoder` works like the following: `fit()` will assess the provided matrix according to its attributes and determine the categories in each of them. As mentioned earlier, `X` apparently has two attributes as stated above. You checked the result with the `categories_` attribute of the fitted encoder. You can see that the encoder found two attributes, and also listed the corresponding categories:

```py
# first attribute with categories Female and Male
array(['Female', 'Male'], dtype=object)

# second attribute with categories 1, 2, 3
array([1, 2, 3], dtype=object)
```

The `transform()` method of `OrdinalEncoder` will encode each attribute as an integer array with the numbers 0 to n_categories - 1. Hence:

```py
['Female', 'Male'] --> [0, 1]

[1, 2, 3] --> [0, 1, 2]
```

With the transformation rule above, you can now see why e.g. `['Female', 3]` will be transformed to `[0, 2]`.

Comment: Thanks. Would you try to explain a little bit the first example? Because I don't see how `fit` and `transform` is taking place.

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope it helps to understand.

Comment: It does, now I see that it encodes "automatically" the values passed. Thanks.